# Swift 3 - UITableViewCell loaded from xib - autolayout and height not correct

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uitableview, swift3

i have a problem about a UITableViewCell which is loaded from a xib and placed into a table. I designed the cell in a xib with a custom height and my stuff. I have my own table:

```
class MyTableView: UITableView, UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate{

    let sections: [String] = ["Section 1", "Section 2", "Section 3"]
    let s1Data: [String] = ["Row 1", "Row 2", "Row 3"]
    let s2Data: [String] = ["Row 1", "Row 2", "Row 3"]
    let s3Data: [String] = ["Row 1", "Row 2", "Row 3"]

    var sectionData: [Int: [String]] = [:]

    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()

        delegate = self
        dataSource = self

        register(UINib(nibName: "MyCell", bundle: nil), forCellReuseIdentifier: "MyCell")

        register(UINib(nibName: "MySection", bundle: nil), forHeaderFooterViewReuseIdentifier: "MySection")

        sectionData = [0:s1Data, 1:s2Data, 2:s3Data]

    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int)
        -> Int {
            return (sectionData[section]?.count)!
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, titleForHeaderInSection section: Int)
        -> String? {
            return sections[section]
    }

    func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return sections.count
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, viewForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> UIView? {

        let section = self.dequeueReusableHeaderFooterView(withIdentifier: "MySection")

        return section

    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

        var cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "MyCell")

        return cell!

    }

}
```

As you can see everything is very basic and I don't cleaned it up yet (just the showcase). The section works fine and is displayed correctly. But MyCell is completly wrong. There's no height applied for the row itself (so the Content is more or less cutted) and the autolayout which I set in the xib is not there. It's just a mess.

In the xib I set the height of the row also like so. 
[image: RowHeight]

I also tried the following two lines:

```
    rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension
    estimatedRowHeight = 96.0
```

In the xib I set the correct constraints in order to force the cell to expand.

The tableview itself is just placed in a ViewController and configured to be a MyTableView-Class.

So why is the height and the autolayout not applied to the cell? Can someone give me an advice here.

**Edit:**

This is the xib file of the cell:

[image: xib]

This is the result of the table:

[image: table]

As you can see the autolayout stuff works now. Maybe there was a fault on my side but the height is still not correct

Comment: If you want static height instead of letting autolayout calculate it for you, set `rowHeight = 96`

Answer (score 1):

I have one solution. I just set a new view in the background or the label itself with a height-constraint which is equal to the cell-height. So in my case 96

[image: set height]

Comment: A little overkill, why using autolayout to calculate the height and then forcing it to a constant?

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you have an actual cell inside the Xib that you put constraints on etc. If that's the case then you should change it to just use an label or what you need instead.

Either way i would recommend making an component of the Xib by creating a class of it's own.

```
class DesignCell: UITableViewCell {

     @IBOutlet weak var headerLabel: UILabel!

     public func configure(withText text: String) {
           headerLabel.text = text
     }
}
```

Now you can use that cell inside your tableView datasource

```
let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: DesignCell.identifier) as! DesignCell
    cell.configure(withText: section[indexPath.item])
    return cell
```

Answer (score 0):

**Delete your:**

`rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension` and

`estimatedRowHeight = 96.0`

Put this method to set height for each row of your table based on your needs:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
    
    return 96
    
}
```

**Or**

Simply`self.tableView.rowHeight = 96` to just set a static height for all your cells.

Comment: Why not simply `rowHeight = 96`?

Comment: But if the OP wants to change `rowHeight` based on various factors, that would do the job, otherwise simple `rowHeight = 96` is sufficient.

Comment: I agree that delegate methods are more flexible, but for static height `rowHeight` is simpler